# Why we need to create xxxCustom and xxxImpl class when we create repository?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

From this information, When we create repository class, it is better to create 1 classes and 2 interfaces for one repository UserRepository(interface), UserRepositoryCustom(class), UserRepositoryImpl(interface).

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

But we can create repository class without these classes... why we need to create those classes and what is the merit(or demerit) if we create those classes?

Comment: What do you mean by "we can create repository class without these classes"? If I understand your question correctly you create 2 interfaces ```UserRepository and UserRepositoryCustom``` and 1 class ```UserRepositoryImpl```.  We never create 3 classes.

Comment: @NitinArora yes, you are right. My question is why we need to create those interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you checkout the Spring Data [core concepts](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts), `UserRepository` interface definition which extends `CrudRepository` or `JPAReposiory` provides you are all basic CRUD operations for free on an entity.

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>
```

You can add your own basic custom queries in this repository interface using the [naming convention approach](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details) or by using [@Query attribute](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query).

In case you want to execute some custom logic which cannot be easily managed and defined in the `UserRepository`, e.g. complex joins and stored procedure and you need access to underlying `EntityManager` you need `UserCustomRepository` interface. `UserRepository` will extend this interface for inheriting the methods.

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, UserCustomRepository {
    void myCustomMethod();
}
```

You need to provide the implementation of these methods yourself in `UserRepositoryImpl` class. Spring data look for custom method implementation in this class and invoke them when they are called.

Hope this explanation helps.

Comment: I realized  that repository class is interface class, not class.thus, it is no way to add new method with some logic. This is why we need to create custom class